# How to fetch data from Mirage in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I need to return a list of users from Mirage. I need this list for rendering it on the front end. How do I do this?

Comment: you should better start with reading [guide](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.3.x/quickstart/) first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install mirage:

```
ember install ember-cli-mirage
```

Once this is done, you need to configure Mirage to send data. This can be done by updating the file `mirage/config.js`.
In the `mirage/config.js` file, its better you define a namespace so that Ember application's call does not conflict with the routes defined already.
Say you want Mirage to return a sample list of users. You can do something like this in the `mirage/config.js` file:

```
export default function() {
  this.namespace = '/api';

  this.get('/users', function() {
    return {
        // list of users
    };
   });
}
```

Now whenever the Ember application makes a get request to `/api/users` , a list of users is returned. 
Only doing this isn't enough, you need to make your application to default making requests to the namespace `/api`.
This is done by creating an application adapter.
To create an application adapter:

```
ember generate adapter application
```

Then in `app/adapters/application.js`, add the namespace like this:

```
export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api'
});
```

Restarting the Ember server would include Mirage in your build.

Say you were making a request for all users in the model function of a route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('users');
  }
})
```

Here, when you request for all the users, Ember data will fetch all users from `/api/users`.